# 2 report templates, but only 1 is printing

Tags: layout, report, odoo, invoice

I have two invoice layouts: account_print_invoice.rml and account_print_invoice_new.rml
I want to add second print action to Print button on invoice form.
I duplicated invoice records in Reports and Action Bindings.
Reports / Name: Invoice New
Reports / Report File:  account/report/account_print_invoice_new.rml
Action Binding / Name: Invoice New
Action Binding / Action Reference:  ir.actions.report.xml,335 - which links to Reports / Invoice New
All the rest of values are the same as default.
Action Binding / Qualifier: client_print_multi

Now Invoice / Print button has two action: Invoice and Invoice New, which is correct.
THE PROBLEM is both print the same layout account_print_invoice_new.rml. I can not print the default account_print_invoice.rml. Why???

I changed Report / Report File in Invoice New to default layout: account/report/account_print_invoice.rml and both print actions use the same DEFAULT layout.
Look like OpenERP takes only one last print action from ir.actions.report.xml with report_name = 'account.invoice'.

What's wrong? Is it a BUG???

Answer (score 0):

What is the report name and xml Id you have used for those reports?